# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - Odoo module migration v8 to v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

Hi I have these three methods:

```
@api.multi
def action_invoice_create(self, wizard_brw, inv_brw): 
    """
    If the invoice has control number, this function is responsible for
    passing the bill to damaged paper
    @param wizard_brw: nothing for now
    @param inv_brw: damaged paper
    """
    invoice_line_obj = self.env['account.invoice.line']
    invoice_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
    acc_mv_obj = self.env['account.move']
    acc_mv_l_obj = self.env['account.move.line']
    tax_obj = self.env['account.invoice.tax']
    invoice = {}
    if inv_brw.nro_ctrl:
        invoice.update({
            'name': 'PAPELANULADO_NRO_CTRL_%s' % (
                inv_brw.nro_ctrl and inv_brw.nro_ctrl or ''),
            'state': 'paid',
            'tax_line': [],
        })
    else:
        raise UserError(
            _('Validation error!'),
            _("You can run this process just if the invoice have Control"
              " Number, please verify the invoice and try again."))
    invoice_obj.write([inv_brw.id], invoice) 
    for line in inv_brw.invoice_line:
        invoice_line_obj.write(
            [line.id],
            {'quantity': 0.0, 'invoice_line_tax_id': [],
             'price_unit': 0.0}) 

    tax_ids = self.env['account.tax'].search([]) 
    tax = tax_obj.search([('invoice_id', '=', inv_brw and inv_brw.id)]) 
    if tax:
        tax_obj.write(tax[0], {'invoice_id': []}) 
    tax_obj.create({
        'name': 'SDCF',
        'tax_id': tax_ids and tax_ids[0],
        'amount': 0.00,
        'tax_amount': 0.00,
        'base': 0.00,
        'account_id': inv_brw.company_id.acc_id.id,
        'invoice_id': inv_brw and inv_brw.id}, {}) 

    if move_id:
        acc_mv_obj.button_cancel([inv_brw.move_id.id]) 
        acc_mv_obj.write([inv_brw.move_id.id],{'ref': 'Damanged Paper'}) 
        acc_mv_l_obj.unlink([i.id for i in inv_brw.move_id.line_id]) 
    return inv_brw.id

@api.multi
def new_open_window(self, list_ids, xml_id, module): 
    """ Generate new window at view form or tree
    """
    mod_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    act_obj = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']
    result = mod_obj._get_id(module, xml_id) 
    imd_id = mod_obj.read(result, ['res_id']) 
    result = act_obj.read(imd_id) 
    result['res_id'] = list_ids
    return result

@api.multi
def create_invoice(self): 
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """
    #context = context or {}
    wizard_brw = self.browse() 
    inv_id = self._context.get('active_id')
    for wizard in wizard_brw:
        if not wizard.sure:
            raise UserError(
                _("Validation error!"),
                _("Please confirm that you know what you're doing by"
                  " checking the option bellow!"))
        if (wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.jour_id and
                wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.acc_id):
            inv_id = self.action_invoice_create(wizard,
                                                wizard.invoice_id) 
        else:
            raise UserError(
                _('Validation error!'),
                _("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
                  " and an account for damaged invoices"))
    return self.new_open_window([inv_id],
                                'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')
```

This is a wizard to declare a damaged paper on invoices, and create a new one, based on that declaration.

When I click on `create_invoice` method it thorws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_invoice_nro_ctrl.py", line 133, in create_invoice
'action_invoice_tree1', 'account') 
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_invoice_nro_ctrl.py", line 105, in new_open_window
imd_id = mod_obj.read(result, ['res_id'])
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 2970, in read
for name in fields:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This is my view:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<odoo>
<data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="wizard_nro_ctrl_form">
        <field name="name">wizard.nro.ctrl.form</field>
        <field name="model">wiz.nroctrl</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Changing the Control Number" version="7.0">
                <field name="name"/>
                <separator string="Are you sure you want to do this?" colspan="4"/>
                <field name="sure"/>
                <button special="cancel" string="Cancel" icon="fa-book"/>
                <button name="set_noctrl" string="Confirm" type="object" icon="fa-pencil-square-o"/>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

 <record id="action_wiz_nroctrl" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Change control number</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
  <field name="res_model">wiz.nroctrl</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">form</field>
  <field name="target">new</field>
</record>

</data>
</odoo>
```

Any ideas?

If You need the old API original code, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure, but form first site, you have a typo.
`mod_obj.read(result, ['res_id'])` returns an id (integer), I believe. It seems you are trying to extract filed from the result twice `mod_obj.read(result, ['res_id'])['res_id'] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
imd_id = mod_obj.read(result, ['res_id']) #returns an integer not a browsable record
```

istead of

```
imd_id = mod_obj.read(result, ['res_id'])['res_id']
```

Comment: @NeoVe "for name in fields:" is the line used in your code?

Comment: But your error is related with read() method ! so check the read syntax in new api here i will gave an example where reading an invoice record
inv.read(['name', 'type', 'number', 'reference',                                 'comment', 'date_due', 'partner_id','partner_insite', 'partner_contact',                               'partner_ref', 'payment_term_id', 'account_id',                                   'currency_id', 'invoice_line_ids', 'tax_line_ids',                                   'journal_id', 'date'])

Comment: Sure, gonna check it, Thank You